# How do I select one value per year from a column of monthly data from a pandas dataframe to plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime

housingData = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\sohan\\Documents\\Documents and Sheets\\Python\\Jupyter\\housingData.csv',error_bad_lines=False, engine="python")

housingData.plot(kind='scatter',y='Average price All property types',x='Pivotable date',color='red')
```

The dates are stored under the header "Pivotable Date" however the issue it contains data for every month, resulting in an unreadable axis. How can I change this to plot only once per year / 6 months etc?
[Picture of the unreadable graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUQK0.png)

Comment: If you make sure that the axis is in datetime format and not string it will look better

Comment: `housingData['Pivotable date'] = pd.to_datetime(housingData['Pivotable date'])`